# How to display the multiple data on sumoselect dropdown from the database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3, sumoselect.js

I am using sumoselect (http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html) and CodeIgniter. I am displaying data from the database. I am inserting product type multiple data in the database like

```
producttype
1
1+2
1+2+3
```

I am displaying like this on HTML page

```
<select name="producttype[]" class="form-control multipleselect event_stop" id="producttype" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
  <option value="1" <?php if($post->producttype =="1") echo 'selected'; ?>>One</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if($post->producttype =="2") echo 'selected'; ?>>Two</option>
  <option value="3" <?php if($post->producttype =="3") echo 'selected'; ?>>Three</option>
  <option value="4" <?php if($post->producttype =="4") echo 'selected'; ?>>Four</option>
</select>
```

If I am getting 1 from the database then select dropdown displaying One but sometimes I am getting 1+2 or 1+2+3 then how can I show in the select dropdown?

Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of sumoselect but it may help you to show selected multiple options as

```
$producttype_array = explode("+","1+2+3");

<select name="producttype[]" class="form-control multipleselect event_stop" id="producttype" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1" <?php if(in_array(1,$producttype_array)) echo 'selected'; ?>>One</option>
  <option value="2" <?php if(in_array(2,$producttype_array)) echo 'selected'; ?>>Two</option>
  <option value="3" <?php if(in_array(3,$producttype_array)) echo 'selected'; ?>>Three</option>
  <option value="4" <?php if(in_array(4,$producttype_array)) echo 'selected'; ?>>Four</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Give me sometime to check this.

Comment: Just now checked your answer.

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. I am getting 1 from the database and in the select dropdown all the checkbox showing selected. Please check this link https://prnt.sc/o2un84

Comment: Some time I am getting 1+2 but in the select dropdown nothing is showing selected.

Comment: Where should I check the output?

Comment: is only selectbox showing multiple selected option?

Comment: No it's not showing. If I am getting multiple product types from the database then select dropdown is not showing selected. If I am getting only one product type then I am getting all the options selected like about Image

Comment: one product type mean 1 or 2 or 3, multiple product type mean 1+2 or 2+3 or 1+2+3. Am i correct?

Comment: Is this correct way to use $producttype_array = explode("+",$post->producttype); ? or should I take $post->producttype as a string?

Comment: obvious 1+2+3 should pass in explode.

Comment: Yes, That's correct, I have to pass in the explode but my the syntax is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195050/discussion-between-questionbank-and-harshwardhan-sharma).

Comment: Thanks for the help and support. Yes, it's working.